# How come Uniswap 0.3 percent pool fee is 3000?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, defi

this is the code from Uniswap docs

```
// For this example, we will set the pool fee to 0.3%.
uint24 public constant poolFee = 3000;
```

how come 0.3% is represented as 3000?

```
  0.3% = 0.3/100 = 3/1000
```

0.3% of 1 million is equal to 3000.

```
   1 000 000 * (3/1000) = 3000
```

Answer (score 3):

By Uniswap conventions, the fee level of a certain pool can have four distinct values:

- 10000 for a 1% fee pool
- 3000 for a 0.3% fee pool
- 500 for a 0.05% pool
- 100 for a 0.01% pool

0.3% or 3000 is also known as 30 bps (basis point).

Answer (score 0):

The answer lays in the fact that the EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine) only works with integers the size of 256 bits (aka 32 bytes).

Since we're working only with integers, we cannot represent fractions such as 0.003 (aka 0.3%) in Solidity. There are plans to add a `ufixed` type but that will also be limited in its capabilities.

Every (rational) fraction can be represented as division between two integers and we can use that fact to treat 0.003 as division between two integers, e.g. `3000` and `1_000_000` or `1e6`.

But if we simply define a `uint` and set its value to `3000/1e6` we will just get `0` because again, the EVM cannot handle fractions, so the number is rounded down to the nearest integer:

```rust
function calcPercent (uint total, uint24 percent) private returns (uint) {
  uint percentValue = percent / 1e6;
  return total * percentValue;
}
```

This will return `0`.

Instead, we must change the order of operations. In the above example, the calculation is `total * (percent / 1e6)`. Instead, we should first multiply the `total` with the `percent` value, then divide:

```rust
function calcPercent (uint total, uint24 percent) private returns (uint) {
  return (total * percent) / 1e6;
}
```

For small `total` values, this will still return `0` but can be considered a rounding error.

In Uniswap specifically they are using a custom math library to achieve a similar & more accurate result. Here's the snippet [from the code](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/d8b1c635c275d2a9450bd6a78f3fa2484fef73eb/contracts/libraries/SwapMath.sol#L41C108-L41C108):

```rust
uint256 amountRemainingLessFee = FullMath.mulDiv(uint256(amountRemaining), 1e6 - feePips, 1e6);
```

The `mulDiv()` function multiplies the first two arguments, then divides by the third. It also uses a bunch of magic tricks to improve precision and guard against overflow. Notice here the outcome is the amount left after deducting the fees, not the fee amount itself, but again the concept is the same.